# SharePoint 2010 Discussion sending Alerts when no updates were made

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have a Discussion board that is sending out "Alert Storms" - notifying all subscribers that 40 - 50 documents have been updated by a given person, even though no changes have been made.

This happens roughly every 4 - 6 weeks.  We have removed all of the Alert subscribers, restarted the server, then re-assigned the Alerts and then six weeks later 52 notifications were sent claiming 52 discussion threads had been updated, when in fact no updates had been made, and no new discussion items had been added.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like Microsoft in Beta to me ...

Comment: do you have any workflow / customization on the disscusion forum? Any Content expiry policy? Did you see any thing in the uls logs when these alerts sent? Did you see last modified date of the post, which is mentioned in the alerts email?